# Evaluating $k$ order derivative of a composition map at some point $t$. Rudin 9.30.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

The problem statment. Let $f\in C^m(E)$, where $E$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R^n}$. Fix $a\in E$, and suppose $x\in \Bbb{R^n}$ is so close to $0$ that the points $p(t) a+ tx$ lie in $E$ whenever $1\geq t\geq0$. Define $h(t)=f(p(t))$ for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$ for which $p(t)\in E$. Problem : For $m\geq k\geq1$, show that $h^{(k)}(t)=\sum(D_{i_1 ...i_k}f)(p(t))x_{i_1}...x_{i_k}$. The sum extends over all ordered k-tuples $(i_1...i_k)$ in which each $i_j$ is one of the integers $1,...,n$.

Using the chain rule repeatedly is recommended, so I computed $$h^{(1)}(t)=h'(t)=f'(p(t))\cdotp p'(t)=\sum_i^n(D_if)(p(t))\cdot x_i$$

But then $h^{(2)}=f''(p(t))\cdot p''(t)=0.$ It doesn't seem like this kind of process will lead towards the answer. Suggestions?

Comment: $h''(t) = (f'(p(t)) p'(t))' = f''(p(t)) p'(t) p'(t) + f'(p(t)) p''(t)$.

Comment: You've now expressed $h'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}f(p)t$ as a sum of terms each of the form $g(p(t))$ for certain functions $g$ (different for each term). If you differentiate $h$ again, each term in that sum is differentiated, and by letting each $g$ take the place of $f$ in the result you already have.